# unable to use set_fact in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, jinja2-cli

unable to use set_fact in ansible. please help me out

```
"msg": [
    "nilaj 15",
    "ajin 15"
]

- set_fact:
     name_list: "{{ name_list + item.split() | first }}" 
     priv_list: "{{ name_list + item.split() | last }}"      
  loop: "{{ user_list }}"

expected output:
name_list = [ "nilamj","ajitn" ]
priv_list = [ "15","15" ]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    user_list:
      - 'nilaj 15'
      - 'ajin 15'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
         name_list: "{{ name_list | d([]) + [item.split() | first] }}"
         priv_list: "{{ priv_list | d([]) + [item.split() | last] }}"
      loop: "{{ user_list }}"

    - debug: var=name_list
    - debug: var=priv_list
...
```

produces:

```json
    "name_list": [
        "nilaj",
        "ajin"
    ]

    "priv_list": [
        "15",
        "15"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to split an array of strings at the space character and divide it into different lists.

I would advise against implementing this as an Ansible loop and use Jinja functionality instead.

You can use the [`map` function](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) to apply the respective filter to each element of the entered list.

Your `set_fact` task would then look like this (without loop):

```yaml
- set_fact:
    name_list: "{{ user_list | map('split') | map('first') }}"
    priv_list: "{{ user_list | map('split') | map('last') }}"
```

1. the filter `split` is applied using `map`
2. the first or last element of the sub-lists is extracted using `map` and the filter `first` or `last`.

---

The input:

```yaml
user_list:
  - 'nilaj 15'
  - 'ajin 15'
```

results in this output:

```
name_list: ['nilaj', 'ajin']
priv_list: ['15', '15']
```